# DB2 connection in a remote system

Tags: db2, telnet, iptables

I have 2 linux systems.
In one system (say, system a)I have a DB2 server installed.
Now I am trying to connect to system a through system b (where I have db2 client installed).
While trying to make the connection I am getting this error
**detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "113", "*",
"*".  SQLSTATE=08001**

So, I tried to do a telnet to system a from system b (for port 50000) , its not working.

I tried to configure iptables in system A (where db2 server resides) by using this command
**iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 50000 -j ACCEPT** 
After that I saved iptables by doing this 
**/sbin/service iptables save**
After that I rebooted server and tried to connect to port 50000 again.
But it is throwing the same error

**telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host**
What am I missing here ?

Comment: Internal firewall?  The telnet error suggests that ip address is just not available on your network.  does ping work?  (Note, pinging from your local machine proves nothing ping from machine b)

Comment: Yes ping works between the machines

Comment: Is there a network filewall or security appliance that is blocking port 50000?

Comment: No there is no security appliance to block port 50000

Comment: There are generally only three possibilities: the DB2 instance is not running; it is listening not on the port you think it does; something (a firewall?) is blocking the port. Check these three things and you will find the answer.

Comment: I have re checked and it seems that db2 in running in port 50000 used this command  grep db2c_db2inst1 /etc/services
out put : db2c_db2inst1   50000/tcp, to unblock the firewall I already made changes in iptables

Comment: What you checked are contents of `/etc/services`; they tell you nothing about whether the DB2 instance is running and whether it's configured to listen on port 50000.